# How to satisfy C6011 error with dynamically allocated array of structures

Tags: visual-c++

We have a heap-allocated array of custom structures that is pointed to by a local pointer. The pointer to the array is checked for nullptr. However, during my loop, VC++ complains that the first attempt to use an indexed entry in the array is "Dereferencing NULL pointer 'ppi'".

I'm having a dumb moment here I think, but there doesn't seem to be any way to satisfy the 6011 warning... how do I correct this scenario?

I have included some snippets of code to briefly illustrate the code in question.

```
// Previously, SystemInfoObject.PeripheralPortInfo is heap-alloc'd to contain 
// multiple PeripheralInfo structures, and 
// SystemInfoObject.PeripheralPortInfoCount is adjusted to the number 
// of elements.

PeripheralInfo *ppi = nullptr;

ppi = SystemInfoObject.PeripheralPortInfo; // Set our local pointer

if (ppi != nullptr)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < SystemInfoObject.PeripheralPortInfoCount; i++)
   {

      if (_tcsncmp(ppi[i].PortName, _T("\\\\"), 2) == 0) // C6011
      {
          // Some code
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio strikes again, I didn't see the loop condition that required certain code later on to change the pointer `ppi` and the null condition was never re-checked on subsequent loop iterations.

Wish I could delete my question! All set!